# Load colors for tailwind.config.ts from API using Nextjs

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I wanted to use React and have SEO, so I chose Next. But I need to load colors that come from the backend to use in `tailwind.config.ts`, but how can I do this using Next?

Comment: what kinda color that come from BE? hex color? or tailwind class like bg-gray-500?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to import data from backend for `tailwindcss.config`

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {
  // ...

  theme: {
    extend: {
      // ...

      colors: {
        // Fetch colors from the API route.
        primary: async () => {
          const response = await fetch('/api/colors');
          const data = await response.json();
          return data.colors.primary || 'red'; // Default color if not found.
        },
        // Add other colors here...
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, thanks everyone!

My `_app.tsx`:

```
import "@src/assets/css/app.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const getColors = async () => {
    const res = fetch("api/colors");
    console.log(res);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let primaryColor = "105, 240, 141";

    const head = document.querySelector("head");
    if (head && !head.textContent.includes(":root")) {
      head.innerHTML += `
        <style>
          :root {
            --primary-color: ${primaryColor};
          }
        </style>
      `;
    }
  });

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

In my `tailwind.config.js`:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: ({ opacityVariable, opacityValue }) => {
          if (opacityValue !== undefined) {
            return `rgba(var(--primary-color), ${opacityValue})`;
          }
          if (opacityVariable !== undefined) {
            return `rgba(var(--primary-color), var(${opacityVariable}, 1))`;
          }
          return `rgb(var(--primary-color))`;
        },
      },
    },
  },
```